# gdalwarp: "ERROR 1" while projecting large dataset (Too many points (..) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.)

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I'm trying to transform a large dataset from `EPSG:4326` to `ESRI:54009` using the `gdalwarp` CLI.

When I try to convert the whole dataset I get ERROR 1 + Warning 1 pairs:

```
$ gdalwarp -of netCDF -co FORMAT=NC4 -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "ESRI:54009" GEBCO_2021.nc GEBCO_2021_Mollweide.nc
Creating output file that is 86400P x 43200L.
Warning 1: projection name Mollweide in not part of the CF standard, will not be supported by CF!
Processing GEBCO_2021.nc [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -32767) for image GEBCO_2021.nc.
Copying nodata values from source GEBCO_2021.nc to destination GEBCO_2021_Mollweide.nc.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,10800,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,5400,5400,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 16200,0,5400,2700, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,32400,5400,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,37800,10800,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 16200,40500,5400,2700, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 64800,0,5400,2700, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 75600,0,10800,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 81000,5400,5400,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 64800,40500,5400,2700, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 81000,32400,5400,5400, skipping.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 75600,37800,10800,5400, skipping.
```

The process then continues and finally creates the dataset.

### Dataset:

[GEBCO_2021 Grid (ice surface elevation)](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/)

### Variations without / less erorrs

If I select a small enough subset of the data and convert it, the number of identical errors reduces down to zero. E.g. this small window works without throwing errors:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF -co FORMAT=NC4 -projwin -180 50 180 40 GEBCO_2021.nc GEBCO_2021_windowed.nc
gdalwarp -of netCDF -co FORMAT=NC4 -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "ESRI:54009" GEBCO_2021_windowed.nc GEBCO_2021_windowed_Mollweide.nc
```

Larger windows throw errors again, e.g. `-projwin -180 50 180 -40` throws 2 ERROR 1.

### Question:

I don't trust the output file created from the full dataset. It's also too large to investigate using e.g. QGIS.

Any ideas how to get rid of the errors?
Or can I just ignore the errors (I presume I can't)?

I'm a beginner with most GIS stuff, so maybe I'm overlooking something very simple.

### Usage context:

The converted dataset is later to be used with `gdaldem` (for slope calculation). Different subsets are then later read using Python (`rasterio`) as input data for a larger workflow.

Comment: Are you not worried about the message `projection name Mollweide in not part of the CF standard, will not be supported by CF!`. But if GDAL converts a small window to "ESRI:54009" then probably that is not critical.

Comment: No, I'm not worried about that warning. I don't deem compliance with the CF standard relevant, as the data is aggregated and combined with other datasets a step later in my workflow anyways. And yes, also like you mention: Since the I was able to produce credible results with the windowed dataset I considered that warning save to be ignored.